# How to print out only the highest count

Tags: java

I am new to java. I want to print out the highest value of a number found in a loop, for an arbitrary number of iterations.

So far I have managed to print the variable on every loop iteration. To keep my example simple I am using the loop counter, `i`, as an example but I would like to know how to do it for any variable, for example a "count" field of a class stored in an array which is iterated using the loop.

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args {
        // could be any number of iterations, e.g. array length
        for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
           System.out.println("Count is: " +    i);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what count are you referring to?

Comment: Surely the simplest answer is `System.out.println(10);` !!

Comment: This question has now been edited to be clear what the problem was. The original close reason is potentially no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to generalise for any number of iterations?

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){       
    max = Math.max(i, max);
}
System.out.println("Count is: " + max);
```

but frankly the Math.max is a big waste of time, you could just do:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){       
    max = i;
}
System.out.println("Count is: " + max);
```

Comment: though i did not ask my question  well, your answer  seems  to capture what i was after. I was after an unknown  number of iterations  in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The highest count here in this program ***within the for-loop*** will be 10 for the value of `i`.

So, you just need to skip all iterations except the last one in which count will be 10.

Using the ***`continue`*** statement,

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++){       
 if(i<10)
  continue;
 else
   System.out.println("Count is: " +    i);
}
```

To get more details about that statement,  [click here...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ForDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){   
        int i;
        for(i=1; i<11; i++){} 

        System.out.println("Count is: " +    i);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning to use streams instead of for loops:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, 11).max().getAsInt());
```